# changing listview value on click in C#

Tags: c#

how can i change the value in the list view by clicking on it
e.g if the value in that column is p and after clicking on that row it replaces only p with a.
it only changes one value and on clicking another row it gives:
InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

```
private void show_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem nlist = new ListViewItem();
    nlist = show.SelectedItems[0];
    if (nlist.SubItems[3].Text == "P")
    {
        nlist.SubItems[3].Text = "A";
    }
    else if (nlist.SubItems[3].Text == "A")
    {
        nlist.SubItems[3].Text = "P";
    }
    else { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if statement inside of your `SelectedIndexChanged` and check whether there is any selected item or not

```
if(show.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    ListViewItem nlist = new ListViewItem();
    nlist = show.SelectedItems[0];
    ...
}
```